# Rails query records based on attribute of a certain association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a three tier model relationship defined like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  scope :with_key, ->(key) { joins(:orders).merge( Order.with_key(key) ) }
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags

  scope :with_key, ->(key) { joins(:tags).merge( Tag.with_key(key) ) }
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  attr_accessible :key

  scope :with_key, ->(key) { where(key: key) }
end
```

Basically a user has many orders and each order has many tags. Tags have a field for `key`. The scope `with_key` allows me to merge-chain several joins as to allow

```
User.with_key("some_key") #=> All users whose orders have a tag with "some_key" as key
```

This is not what I need, however.
How do I find all users whose **last** order's tags have "some_key" as the key?